# Mounting a remote disk image which I made local via sshfs? Possible?

Tags: mount, ext4, fuse

The core question first:
*Is sshfs fit to provide low-level reads/writes/seeks as required when a file contains blockdevice-like contents?*

Why? Well...
I am trying to locally mount a filesystem-image, for example a file ext4.img, while the filesystem-image actually resides on a remote server but is mounted somewhere local via sshfs. So far, sshfs seems to be fit, but I am still unsure if the errors I am getting come from sshfs or the mount driver.

I tried it with ext4, to test drive the fuseext2 driver:

Remote /some/path/ext4.img is mounted via sshfs to /mnt/remote/ext4.img
Then I issued "fuseext2 /mnt/remote/ext4.img mnt -o rw+" to mount the remote image, which is by then local, to /mnt/mnt

This basically works, but gives strange and occasional read errors on larger files, like JPGs.

I would prefer to use "mount -o loop ...", but that gives the "No permissions" error and I don't know why. Pointers on my actual setup welcome, but essentially, this here is about:

Can I use sshfs to provide the underpinnings for a pseudo-block-device?